# Align items vertically in a center - Sencha Panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to align mid of the screen of an item simply a `label` but it is aligning it horizontally not vertically.

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout:{
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'My Label'
        }
    ],
    fullscreen: true,
    flex: 1
});
```

I have removed `flex`, and set `height` as well, but it doesn't work. Please give me some clue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `pack: center` in the layout, like this:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    }, 
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'My Label'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It controls how the child items of the container are packed together. Like `center` makes the child items packed together at mid-width of container.

Comment: this doesn't work for my panel. I have as items a label and a button

Answer (score 4):

For HBox layout preferable to use 'align: middle' config I suppose.
Try this:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle'
    }, 
    items:[{
        xtype:'label',
        html:'My Label'
    }]
});
```